# How do I use a multiplexer to select a logic function?

Tags: circuit-design, multiplexer, homework, logisim

I have a homework assignment where I'm supposed to use 4:1 multiplexers to select from one of four logic functions in Logisim. However, my only experience with multiplexers in Logisim up to this point was designing a circuit using 2:1s and passing the output of the multiplexer to the output of the circuit.

So, how do I use a multiplexer to select a logic function? Do I use a splitter at the multipexer's output? Do I set the data bits in Logisim to 4?

Comment: You can cascade multiplexers to build larger ones. If you have 2:1 muxes available, you can make a 4:1 out of three 2:1's.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to code...

RTL?  you could use a case statement.  Does it specify how many selection bits to use?  you need 2 selection bits for 4 inputs, but if it explicitly states 4 selection bits, it is probably trying to teach you about one-hot encoding... maybe, or possibly unused inputs.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that my only experience with multiplexers in Logisim was designing a circuit using 2:1's and passing the output of the multiplexer to the output of the circuit.

Comment: It's the same process for 4:1, just that you have a decode/selection for 0,1,2,3, instead of just 0,1.  You need at least 2 bits for selection. "00" for 0, "01" for 1, "10" for 2, "11" for 3.  (or the aforementioned one-hot scheme using 4 bits).